# NA values not being excluded in `cor`

Tags: r, na

To simplify, I have a data set which is as follows:

```
b <- 1:6
# > b
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
jnk <- c(2, 4, 5, NA, 7, 9)
# > jnk
# [1]  2  4  5 NA  7  9
```

When I try:

```
cor(b, jnk, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get:

```
> cor(b, jnk, na.rm=T)
  Error in cor(b, jnk, na.rm = T) : unused argument (na.rm = T)
```

I've also tried `na.action = na.exclude`, etc. None seem to work. It'd be really helpful to know what the issue is and how I can fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 89):

**TL; DR:**  Use instead:

```
cor(b, jnk, use="complete.obs")
```

---

Read `?cor`:

```
cor(x, y = NULL, use = "everything",
     method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
```

It doesn't have `na.rm`, it has `use`.

> an optional character string giving a method for computing covariances in the presence of missing values. This must be (an abbreviation of) one of the strings `"everything"`, `"all.obs"`, `"complete.obs"`, `"na.or.complete"`, or `"pairwise.complete.obs"`.

Pick one. Details of what each does is in the `Details` section of `?cor`.

Comment: A very annoying part about `R` is the inconsistency w.r.t. `na.rm` and its variants...

Comment: at least `help(foo)` is consistent.

Comment: Yes. Still I hope they (in all `base`/out of the box functions, at least) unify at some point...

Comment: Brilliant thank you! For anyone else looking for the qiock solution, to exclude NA's from the cor() function, use the argument: use="complete.obs"

use="complete.obs"

Answer (score 11):

Just to make sure the answer to this question is clear.

To ignore NA, use

```
b <- 1:6
jnk <- c(2, 4, 5, NA, 7, 9)
cor(b, jnk, use="complete.obs")
[1] 0.9905977
```